# Rabbitmq allow only one concurrent consumer

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-framework-beans

Is there anyway to have a standby consumer that is only used if the primary consumer goes down?

If i have two instance of my same application and that application has listener which listen to "queue1" then the current behaviour is if one consumer is busy then another consumer take the data and read it. But i don't want that.

I need only consumer1 can read the queue and consumer2 is in idle state till consumer1 goes down.

I have tried exclusive also but that it doesn't fulfil my requirements.

Can somebody help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a feature of RabbitMQ nor the Spring framework. You will have to implement failover yourself in your consumers. One option would be for the "master" consumer to publish heartbeat messages to a well-known queue that the failover consumer could read. If the failover consumer does not receive a certain number of heartbeat messages from this queue within a certain time period, it can do additional checks to see if the master consumer is alive, and, if not, take over that role.

This is just one suggestion - there are many ways to implement this.